# I'm trying to iterate over a list I pass to my function but get:'int' object is not iterable compile error

Tags: python, mobile

Here is my code. Just trying to sum any number in the (input) list that doesn't repeat.

I just don't understand why it won't compile. It just says the above type error.

```
def sum(input):
unique=[];
sum=0;
multiple=[];
for i in input:
  found=False;
  inMultiple=False;
  inUnique=False;
  for j in multiple:
    if i==j:
      found=True;
      inMultiple=True;
  for j in unique:
    if i==j:
      found=True;
      inUnique=True;
  if not(found):
    unique+=i;
  else:
    if inUnique:
      unique.remove(i);
      if not(inMultiple):
        multiple+=i;
for i in unique:
   sum+=i;
return sum;
list =[1,1,2,3];
print(sum(list));
```

Comment: Look at this line: `unique+=i` `unique` appears to be a list and `i`  appears to be an integer. What are you hoping this does?

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: @Mark I'm hoping that that line adds element I to the list unique.

Comment: @JohnGordon I though that it was referring to line 5 where the for each begins but it looks like the actually traceback was for line 18. Which is unique +=i

Comment: Using `+=` is the wrong way to add an item to a list (unless the item you're adding is itself a list, which in this case it is not).  Use `.append()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I just think you have made the code too complex but your idea is perfect
Using predefined function names can also cause issues too. (eg. input, sum are predefined functions in python.). I have written code using Hashmap(dictionary) which might help you with same logic as you used.

```
def sum1(list1):
    # Keep count of each element  and then take sum only those which occur ONLY once
    #Just for better understanding I have also stored the sum of the multiple terms
    dict1={}
    for num in list1:
        if num not in dict1.keys():
            dict1[num]=1
        else:
            dict1[num]+=1
    ans_unique=0    # Variable to store  unique elements
    ans_multiple=0  # Variable to store  unique elements
    for key in dict1.keys():
        if dict1[key]==1:# Unique
            ans_unique+=key
        else:
            ans_multiple+=key
    
    return ans_unique
    
     


list1 =[1,1,2,3]
print(sum1(list1))
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Just trying to sum any number in the (input) list that doesn't repeat. ..."*

Here is an example.
Traverse *a*, appending the value to *b*, only if the remaining items in *a*, do not include another instance.

```py
import random as r
a, b = sorted([r.randint(1, 20) for x in range(20)]), []
for i, v in enumerate(a):
    if v not in a[i + 1:]: b.append(v)
x = sum(b)
```

Output

```
a = [2, 2, 3, 3, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16, 16, 18, 19, 20]
b = [2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20]
sum of b = 170
```

> *"... I just don't understand why it won't compile. It just says the above type error. ..."*

Here is the error I get, with your code.

```
    return sum;
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

You'll need to place your code within a *function*.

Here is the *Python* tutorial, on *"Defining Functions"*.
*[The Python Tutorial — Python 3.12.0 documentation – 4.7. Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)*.